# Facing sonar Quality issue after adding exclusion in pom file

Tags: sonarqube

After adding the <sonar.coverage.exclusions> in pom.xml file sonar is still giving quality issue, i have excluded the file as well.

Properties of POM XML

[image]

PlugIn in POM xml

[image]

Sonar fail image

[image]

I have excluded the some files but sill sonar is not excluding those files.